# Why doesn’t "composer update" upgrade this site?

Tags: composer, upgrading, 10

I'm running Drupal 9.59. I tried following the instructions on drupal.org for upgrading to Drupal 10. The steps with `composer --no-update` went fine. The actual update step yields:

> Loading composer repositories with package information
> Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
> Updating dependencies
> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
>
> Problem 1
>
> - drupal/core 8.0.0-beta6 requires doctrine/common dev-master#a45d110f71c323e29f41eb0696fa230e3fa1b1b5 -> found doctrine/common[dev-remove-int-cast, 2.1.3, ..., 2.13.x-dev, 3.0.0, ..., 3.5.x-dev] but it does not match the constraint.
> - drupal/core[8.0.0-beta13, ..., 8.0.0-beta15] require guzzlehttp/guzzle dev-master#1879fbe853b0c64d109e369c7aeff09849e62d1e -> found guzzlehttp/guzzle[v1.0.3, v1.0.4, v2.0.0, ..., v2.8.8, v3.0.0, ..., v3.8.1, 4.0.0-rc.1, ..., 4.x-dev, 5.0.0, ..., 5.3.x-dev, 6.0.0, ..., 6.5.x-dev, 7.0.0-beta.1, ..., 7.7.x-dev] but it does not match the constraint.
> - zendframework/zend-feed[dev-master, dev-develop, 2.11.0, ..., 2.13.x-dev] require php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.1.16) does not satisfy that requirement.
> - laminas/laminas-feed[2.12.0, ..., 2.12.x-dev] require php ^5.6 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.1.16) does not satisfy that requirement.
> - symfony/psr-http-message-bridge[v1.1.0, ..., 1.1.x-dev] require php ^5.3.3 || ^7.0 -> your php version (8.1.16) does not satisfy that requirement.
> - symfony-cmf/routing[1.4.0-RC1, ..., 1.4.x-dev] require php ^5.3.9|^7.0 -> your php version (8.1.16) does not satisfy that requirement.
> - symfony/psr-http-message-bridge[v1.2.0, ..., v1.3.0] require php ^7.1 -> your php version (8.1.16) does not satisfy that requirement.
> - drupal/core[8.9.11, ..., 8.9.x-dev] require php ^7.0.8 -> your php version (8.1.16) does not satisfy that requirement.
> - drupal/core[9.0.10, ..., 9.0.x-dev] require php ^7.3 -> your php version (8.1.16) does not satisfy that requirement.
> - laminas/laminas-feed[2.13.0, ..., 2.14.x-dev] require php ^7.3 || ~8.0.0 -> your php version (8.1.16) does not satisfy that requirement.
> - Root composer.json requires drupal/token_filter ^1.4 -> satisfiable by drupal/token_filter[1.4.0, 1.x-dev].
> - drupal/core-recommended 10.0.0-alpha1 requires drupal/core 10.0.0-alpha1 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.0.0-alpha1].
> - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 10.0.0-alpha1 (conflict analysis result)
> - drupal/core-recommended 10.0.0-alpha2 requires drupal/core 10.0.0-alpha2 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.0.0-alpha2].
> - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 10.0.0-alpha2 (conflict analysis result)
> - drupal/core-recommended 10.0.0-alpha3 requires drupal/core 10.0.0-alpha3 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.0.0-alpha3].
> - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 10.0.0-alpha3 (conflict analysis result)
> - drupal/core-recommended 10.0.0-alpha4 requires drupal/core 10.0.0-alpha4 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.0.0-alpha4].
> - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 10.0.0-alpha4 (conflict analysis result)
> - drupal/core-recommended 10.0.0-alpha5 requires drupal/core 10.0.0-alpha5 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.0.0-alpha5].
> - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 10.0.0-alpha5 (conflict analysis result)
> - drupal/core-recommended 10.0.0-alpha6 requires drupal/core 10.0.0-alpha6 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.0.0-alpha6].
> - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 10.0.0-alpha6 (conflict analysis result)
> - drupal/core-recommended 10.0.0-alpha7 requires drupal/core 10.0.0-alpha7 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.0.0-alpha7].
> - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 10.0.0-alpha7 (conflict analysis result)
> - drupal/core-recommended 10.1.0-alpha1 requires drupal/core 10.1.0-alpha1 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.1.0-alpha1].
> - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 10.1.0-alpha1 (conflict analysis result)
> - drupal/core-recommended 10.0.0-beta1 requires drupal/core 10.0.0-beta1 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.0.0-beta1].
> - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 10.0.0-beta1 (conflict analysis result)
> - drupal/core-recommended 10.0.0-beta2 requires drupal/core 10.0.0-beta2 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.0.0-beta2].
> - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 10.0.0-beta2 (conflict analysis result)
> - drupal/core-recommended 10.1.0-beta1 requires drupal/core 10.1.0-beta1 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.1.0-beta1].
> - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 10.1.0-beta1 (conflict analysis result)
> - drupal/core-recommended 10.0.0-rc1 requires drupal/core 10.0.0-rc1 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.0.0-rc1].
> - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 10.0.0-rc1 (conflict analysis result)
> - drupal/core-recommended 10.0.0-rc2 requires drupal/core 10.0.0-rc2 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.0.0-rc2].
> - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 10.0.0-rc2 (conflict analysis result)
> - drupal/core-recommended 10.0.0-rc3 requires drupal/core 10.0.0-rc3 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.0.0-rc3].
> - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 10.0.0-rc3 (conflict analysis result)
> - drupal/core-recommended 10.1.0-rc1 requires drupal/core 10.1.0-rc1 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.1.0-rc1].
> - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 10.1.0-rc1 (conflict analysis result)
> - drupal/core-recommended 10.0.0 requires drupal/core 10.0.0 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.0.0].
> - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 10.0.0 (conflict analysis result)
> - drupal/core-recommended 10.0.1 requires drupal/core 10.0.1 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.0.1].
> - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 10.0.1 (conflict analysis result)
> - drupal/core-recommended 10.0.2 requires drupal/core 10.0.2 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.0.2].
> - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 10.0.2 (conflict analysis result)
> - drupal/core-recommended 10.0.3 requires drupal/core 10.0.3 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.0.3].
> - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 10.0.3 (conflict analysis result)
> - drupal/core-recommended 10.0.4 requires drupal/core 10.0.4 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.0.4].
> - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 10.0.4 (conflict analysis result)
> - drupal/core-recommended 10.0.5 requires drupal/core 10.0.5 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.0.5].
> - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 10.0.5 (conflict analysis result)
> - drupal/core-recommended 10.0.6 requires drupal/core 10.0.6 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.0.6].
> - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 10.0.6 (conflict analysis result)
> - drupal/core-recommended 10.0.7 requires drupal/core 10.0.7 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.0.7].
> - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 10.0.7 (conflict analysis result)
> - drupal/core-recommended 10.0.8 requires drupal/core 10.0.8 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.0.8].
> - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 10.0.8 (conflict analysis result)
> - drupal/core-recommended 10.0.9 requires drupal/core 10.0.9 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.0.9].
> - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 10.0.9 (conflict analysis result)
> - drupal/core-recommended 10.1.0 requires drupal/core 10.1.0 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.1.0].
> - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 10.1.0 (conflict analysis result)
> - drupal/core[8.4.0-alpha1, ..., 8.7.7] require symfony-cmf/routing ^1.4 -> satisfiable by symfony-cmf/routing[1.4.0-RC1, ..., 1.4.x-dev].
> - drupal/core[8.2.0-beta1, ..., 8.3.x-dev] require symfony-cmf/routing ~1.4 -> satisfiable by symfony-cmf/routing[1.4.0-RC1, ..., 1.4.x-dev].
> - drupal/core[9.0.0-alpha1, ..., 9.0.0-alpha2] require symfony/psr-http-message-bridge ^1.2.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/psr-http-message-bridge[v1.2.0, v1.3.0].
> - drupal/core[8.7.8, ..., 8.9.10] require symfony/psr-http-message-bridge ^1.1.2 -> satisfiable by symfony/psr-http-message-bridge[v1.1.2, 1.1.x-dev, v1.2.0, v1.3.0].
> - drupal/core[8.8.0-alpha1, ..., 8.8.x-dev] require zendframework/zend-feed ^2.12 -> satisfiable by laminas/laminas-feed[2.12.0, ..., 2.21.x-dev], zendframework/zend-feed[2.12.0, 2.12.x-dev, 2.13.x-dev].
> - drupal/core-recommended 10.1.x-dev requires drupal/core 10.1.x-dev -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.1.x-dev].
> - Conclusion: don't install drupal/core 10.1.x-dev (conflict analysis result)
> - drupal/token_filter[1.4.0, ..., 1.x-dev] require drupal/core ^8 || ^9 -> satisfiable by drupal/core[8.0.0-beta6, ..., 8.9.x-dev, 9.0.0-alpha1, ..., 9.5.x-dev].
> - You can only install one version of a package, so only one of these can be installed: drupal/core[8.0.0-beta6, ..., 8.9.x-dev, 9.0.0-alpha1, ..., 9.5.x-dev, 10.0.0-alpha1, ..., 10.1.x-dev].
> - You can only install one version of a package, so only one of these can be installed: drupal/core[8.0.0-beta12, ..., 8.9.x-dev, 9.0.0-alpha1, ..., 9.5.x-dev, 10.0.0-alpha1, ..., 10.1.x-dev].
> - You can only install one version of a package, so only one of these can be installed: drupal/core[8.1.2, ..., 8.9.x-dev, 9.0.0-alpha1, ..., 9.5.x-dev, 10.0.0-alpha1, ..., 10.1.x-dev].
> - You can only install one version of a package, so only one of these can be installed: drupal/core[8.1.8, ..., 8.9.x-dev, 9.0.0-alpha1, ..., 9.5.x-dev, 10.0.0-alpha1, ..., 10.1.x-dev].
> - You can only install one version of a package, so only one of these can be installed: drupal/core[8.7.0-alpha1, ..., 8.9.x-dev, 9.0.0-alpha1, ..., 9.5.x-dev, 10.0.0-alpha1, ..., 10.1.x-dev].
> - drupal/core-recommended 10.0.x-dev requires drupal/core 10.0.x-dev -> satisfiable by drupal/core[10.0.x-dev].
> - Root composer.json requires drupal/core-recommended ^10 -> satisfiable by drupal/core-recommended[10.0.0-alpha1, ..., 10.1.x-dev].
>
> composer [update] failed, composer command failed: exit status 2. stderr=

I'm stumped. I tried removing the lock file, but no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start by fixing each issue, starting with “drupal/token_filter[1.4.0, ..., 1.x-dev] require drupal/core ^8 || ^9”.

As far as I know all upgrade guides recommend updating contributed modules first and using readiness reports.

Comment: Except the main one, so far. https://www.drupal.org/docs/upgrading-drupal/upgrading-from-drupal-8-or-later/upgrading-a-composer-based-site

Comment: The doc says to begin with composer require 'drupal/core-recommended:^10' 'drupal/core-composer-scaffold:^10' 'drupal/core-project-message:^10' --update-with-dependencies --no-update, then composer require 'drupal/recommended-project:^10' --update-with-dependencies --no-update, after which it says drupal/recommended-project cannot require itself in composer.json.

Comment: The overview of that docs section says to upgrade contributed projects, first thing: https://www.drupal.org/docs/upgrading-drupal/upgrading-from-drupal-8-or-later/upgrading-from-drupal-9-to-drupal-10/overview

Comment: That last statement couldn't be more important - I just went through this process on a large, complex site yesterday. Making sure that everything was at latest versions, and updating constraints for contrib modules with a release _only_ for D10 (not 9&10) were represented, e.g. `^2.0 || ^3.0`, made everything go smoothly

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend doing a `composer update drupal/core-recommended -W` (with all dependencies). Seems the guzzle items aren't marked for update. Also make sure your contributed modules are updated to the latest versions as well. Also a nice `composer why-not drupal/core-recommended:^10` may give more information. Finally if that doesn't work, install drupal/upgrade_status and run a report which may tell more.

Comment: Upgrade_status declared almost all being well other than fontyourface and stable. That might be part of what has me hosed…my theme uses stable as its base. I just tried stable9 and that was no good. This might get painful.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/stable is a drop-in replacement for core stable. Literally tested it yesterday and works a treat, you just need to install it in the D9 site first, part of the "upgrade contributed projects first" requirement that cilefen mentioned in comments on the other answer

Comment: I've gone through and updated or removed all until upgrade status is all green. When I try to update to 10.1.1 (composer require drupal/core-recommended:^10.1.1 drupal/core-composer-scaffold:^10.1.1 drupal/core-project-message:^10.1.1 --update-with-all-dependencies) I get "...require psr/container ~2.0.2 -> found psr/container[dev-master, 2.0.2, 2.0.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require"

Comment: Cilifen's answer ultimately got me to the correct place. To get upgrade_status to all be green, some modules (eg fontyourface) needed to be removed. Removing the lock file and the vendor folder helped too. I tried using 10.1.1 on the update command, as mentioned above, but that put me into that psr hell. Changing it back to simply ^10 ultimately worked.